# Make Google+ button ignore and div of images on a blog page

Tags: wordpress, google-plus, google-plus-one, facebook-sharer

I have an blog with related posts image in the top of it. I was waiting for something to fix it since they launch it, but didn't find anything yet so I'm asking for help with it.

The question is. When someone share an post with +1 button, it get the first image of the URL, which usually is one of the featured posts thumbnail.

In Facebook Share I got an plugin that get the 'featured image', but as far I researched, didn't find anyway to make it possible with G+.

So, one of the solutions I considered is making the "Featured post thumbnails" div 'hidden' to G+ button. Is it possible? Or make something similar?

Comment: Do your posts generally have images that you want used instead?

Comment: Almost all posts have featured imagens. If don't, FB Share will use the Blog Logo. Something like that would be great for +1 share too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the +[Snippet](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet) values. In the case where a post has no image make sure you keep the image definition but use the blog logo instead.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="image-url"></img>
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: So, inside the 'src' I can use the featured image from each post or something that isn't always the same image?

Comment: Inside of `src` you can use whatever image URL you want as long as it fits the +1 size requirements in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Abraham's way, you can specify the og: meta data tags in the `<head>` section of your blog posts.  See http://ogp.me for more information about the og: meta tags.  The one you need is `<og:image />`.

IIRC, Wordpress has plugins that allow you to specify og tags.

Comment: The image que be relative to each post? I will try both ways, really thanks.

Comment: Yes, the image can be specific to each post.  Each post has a canonical URL, correct?

Comment: I checked that now and the "SEO for WordPress by Yoast" plugin already use and configure all the og meta tags. I will try what Abraham commented.

Comment: Sadly not. I just remove the banner with image it was before the content. I will fix it soon as I can.

Comment: I think I "fixed" the problem placing the featured posts Div on footer, so in the code the featured images will come only in the end. Well, at least is working for now.